# hashmap general modification

Tags: c++

Ok so i wrote a c++ websocket server took a while but i think i did good job for a intermediate programmer but have a question my friend suggested that i use hash_map from the namespace __gnu_cxx; it all builds fine and what not i just want to know say i need to change a users name in one of the user fields would it update just by doing this

_userslist[id].name = "BlaBla Bla";

or would i need to replace the entire field with a copy but with name changed.

i would try it but when ever i take the server down all my members moan and moan so thought id ask here :)

Thanks
Dave

Comment: on another note anyone know whats best hash_map which is depreciated or one of the std:: maps

Comment: You're asking us a fairly specific question about code that we can't see. Without knowing what type `_userslist` is or what `name` is it's going to be pretty hard for us to answer.

Comment: http://thecoderguy.org/ss/20121016-xs9-11kb.jpg and name is std::string the win user class looks like http://thecoderguy.org/ss/20121016-ec0-58kb.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely `_userslist[id]` will return a `WinUser&`, assuming `_userslist` is not const in this context. If `name` is a public member of `WinUser` that has an `operator=` that takes a `const char *` (or something `const char *` can convert into), then it will work.

Comment: I explained very precisely the circumstances under which it will work. 1) `_userslist` must not be const in this context. 2) `_userslist[id]` must return `WinUser&`. 3) `WinUser` must have a public member called `name`. 4) `name` must have an `operator=` that can take a `const char *` (or something a `const char *` can convert into). If those things are all the case, then it will work. If not, then it won't.